# Jquery Onchange event not being triggered

Tags: php, jquery, onchange

I have an onChange event, but upon change it is not being triggered. I have verified I am calling the fields correctly.

```
    $("#SRIEquipmentDDL").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "3") {
        $("#SRILift").show();
    } else {
        $("#SRILift").hide();
    }
});

<div id="SRIEquipment">
            <div class="TextField">Equipment:</div>
            <div class="InputField">
                <select name="SRIEquipmentDDL" id="SRIEquipmentDDL" class="DropDownField">
                    <option value="0" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "0") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >Select Chair Type</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "1") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >Manual Wheelchair</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "2") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Power Wheelchair</option>
                    <option value="3" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "3") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Lift Chair</option>
                    <option value="4" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "4") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Scooter</option>
                    <option value="5" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "5") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Lifts</option>
                    <option value="6" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "6") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>CPM</option>
                    <option value="8" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "7") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Walker</option>                          
                    <option value="9" <?php if ($_POST['SRIEquipmentDDL'] == "8") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SRILift">
            <div class="TextField">Lift Type:</div>
            <div class="InputField">
                <select name="SRILiftTypeDDL" id="SRILiftTypeDDL" class="DropDownField">
                    <option value="0" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "0") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >Select Lift Type</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "1") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >Stair Lift</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "2") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Porch Lift</option>
                    <option value="3" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "3") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Outside Vehicle Lift</option>
                    <option value="4" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "4") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Inside Vehicle Lift</option>
                    <option value="5" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "5") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Ceiling Lift</option>                     
                    <option value="6" <?php if ($_POST['SRILiftTypeDDL'] == "6") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the onChange event bound after the page is loaded?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to bind the event handler before the element exists. Please read the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) to learn how to set up jQuery properly. Also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196.

Comment: yes.  $(document).ready(function (){ I have this at the start of the jquery document under the header.

Comment: Please define "upon change". Does anything happen if you chose an item then click somewhere else on the page, giving the focus to another field?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 $('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $('#yourSelectId option:selected').attr('value');
});
```

make sure you code is inside a ready function - http://api.jquery.com/ready/
or it is after the HTML that create the select

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){ is at the start I'm talking just about what triggers it. I have other onChange events like this that work fine, It is just this one that is not working.

Comment: I am not, which is weird. I'm going to try a few different method will post if none or one of the works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that often select boxes will not fire the change event while they are `focused`.

Since you are using JQuery, the solution is to use `.click()` in conjunction with `.blur()` in order to trigger the `onchange` event.

I found this Fiddle which demonstrates what you'll want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/wLWMc/

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the  the jquery bind() method??
If it doesn't work try to check the value inside your 
select ...may be there are INTEGERS try then 
change your condition to :

if ($(this).val() == 3) {

Comment: `.change` and `.bind` just call `.on` internally. Switching the method would not make a difference.

Comment: .bind has been deprecated since 1.7, use .on instead

Answer (score -1):

Try using live in your code

```
 $("#SRIEquipmentDDL").on('change',function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "3") {
                $("#SRILift").show();
            } else {
                $("#SRILift").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: .live has been deprecated since 1.7, use .on instead